# Dealing with unintentionally racist/offensive behavior of new country

Tags: netherlands, racial-issues

I'm American, considering taking a job in the Netherlands. My research into living into the Netherlands has predominantly been great, except for one very worrisome thing. [Zwarte Piet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwarte_Piet). I was looking at schools for my young son and saw several pictures of them celebrating this and there were several teachers in black face. It's one thing to have read about it, but it was a bit staggering to see that it is truly a common part of the culture.

I am white, my wife is black and our two sons are a pleasantly tan color (but in comparison to your prototypical white person, they would readily be considered black).

In preparation for possibly moving there, how do I properly address something that I find, and my wife finds even more so, offensive but is just a fairly common part of the culture?

I'm not even fully sure how to explain why it's offensive/racist, I'm sure my wife could better explain it. To add to the possible difficulty, coworkers who haven't interacted with my family may have no idea my wife and children are black (not that it matters, but it seems like that might give more credence to my claims that it's offensive in their eyes).

Comment: Welcome to IPS! I might just be tired but I'm not sure I fully understand the question. So, you would like to talk to the school to make them understand that the Zwarte Piet celebration is racist. Is that correct? And you would like to do the same with your coworker too? (if it's correct, please [edit] your question to make it clearer)

Comment: This is a great question, the only things I want clarification on are specific instances of dealing with this- for example, maybe if a co-worker asks if you celebrate it or like it, or answering questions about it? Can you provide an example of the situation so we can better understand and answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: @Noon, basically yeah. It's more about pre-planning in advance for what is likely to come up.

Comment: @ElizB, I can't provide any scenario because it's currently theoretical. I just know that Zwarte Piet is a common enough thing in the Netherlands that I feel I should have a plan in place for when, not if, it comes up, either professionally or personally.

Comment: Can you pick a category- professional or personal? Both have very different sets of interpersonal skills and different expectations of social behavior. To better answer your question, can it be narrowed down?

Comment: J.Doe What would you like to plan for? We might be able to help with hypothetical situations, but just like questions about real situations, they need enough detail and a goal to work towards to. Right now, this is incredibly broad, as answers could focus on dealing with confused kids, offended wives, and/or protesting against something as an 'outsider'. Also... it's pretty important to have this explicit: but 'properly address' would likely mean 'distance myself from it' or 'not celebrate Sinterklaasfeest if there's Zwarte Pieten'?

Comment: Side question: How do you/your wife feel about 'roetveegpieten' or 'regenboogpieten'? (Asking because some people feel Piet should go entirely, and others just want to get rid of the blackface)

Comment: Hi @J.Doe Have you also considered asking this question over on the [Expatriates Stack Exchange?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) I'm not fully up on their rules but a question about emigration to a country and dealing with potential issues around racist/offensive behaviours/traditions could be something they can also help with or have experience having dealt with (and therefore possible solutions).

Comment: (As I've been told google doesn't translate 'roetveegpiet' or 'regenboogpiet': The first are a version of Black Pete with just black soot stripes on their face, to match the story that Black Pete is black due to travelling down chimneys to deliver presents in shoes set before bedtime near a hearth/radiator. The second ones are rainbowcoloured versions of Black Pete, these have faces and hands painted a solid bright colour like yellow, green, blue, pink, etc.)

Comment: *How do I properly address [...]?* - this seems too hypothetical and general to allow a good answer. If you run into concrete situations in which this plays a role and ask a question about that, it can be answered.

Comment: This subject is extremely controversial, but the opinion does differ some by region. Don't mention being against blackface in the hamlet I was born, lest you get an angry mob running after you with pitchforks. In the Randstad (the area inbetween and including Amsterdam and Rotterdam), a 'different' opinion is more accepted. Do you have any idea what region you'll be moving to?